# Memory leak in Depth First Search Algorithm on Graphs

Tags: c++, memory, graph-algorithm, depth-first-search

I was doing a course on Coursera where they asked to implement DFS to see if two vertices of a graph are connected. I came up with the code and it gives the correct output on my laptop but it gives incorrect output on their grader. I've been breaking my head for days on this problem and have absolutely no idea where I've gone wrong. The code is as follows:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
class Graph
{
public:

    vector<int> adj; //adjacency list
    void add(int a)
    {
        adj.push_back(a);
    }

    void DFS(bool visited[],int n,Graph G[],int v)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<G[v].adj.size();i++)
        {
            int vert=G[v].adj[i];
            if(visited[vert]==false)
            {
                visited[vert]=true;
                DFS(visited,n,G,vert);
            } 
        }
    }
};
int main()
{
    int n,m;
    cin>>n>>m;//No. of vertices,number of edges
    bool visited[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        visited[n]=false;
    Graph G[n];
    for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        int u,v;
        cin>>u>>v;  //The vertices joined by two edges
        G[u-1].add(v-1);
        G[v-1].add(u-1);
    }
    int k,l;
    cin>>k>>l; //The vertices to be checked if they are connected
    G[k-1].DFS(visited,n,G,k-1);
    if(visited[l-1]==true)
        cout<<1;
    else
        cout<<0;
}
```

Grader Output:

```
Failed case #2/16: (Wrong answer)

Input:
4 2
1 2
3 2
1 4

Your output: 
1
Correct output:
0
(Time used: 0.00/1.00, memory used: 7839744/536870912.)
```

If I run the above case in my laptop, it gives the output as 0, the expected answer. I asked the question on the forum and they say that there is some memory leak which I can't identify. Please help.

Comment: Use valgrind to identify errors.

Comment: I appreciate the completeness of the question, but I still need to convert it to standard c++. Looking. (avoid VLA) Also there is a forum on coursera for these questions, which might have been a better choice (because it has other people doing the same assignments).

Comment: There may be a problem initializing visited.

Comment: I do not see any memory leak, but memory corruption during the initialization of the `visited` structure. You set `visited[n] = false` while it should be `visited[i] = false`. `visited[n]` is outside of the structure so you are corrupting memory, and you are not properly initializing the structure. Correct this and you code will work as expected.

Comment: `bool visited[n];` is not standard C++, it is recommended to program to the standard. Your Graph class should be named Vertex. DFS should not be a member function of that class. There are no memory leaks here. A memory leak cannot make a right answer into a wrong one anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing a `Graph` class, then you should really encapsulate all functionality inside that class. You're not supposed to overwhelm the `main` function. It makes your code convoluted. Plus you don't have to pass around a lot things in case of a function call. Avoid using `using namespace std;` as it will lead to namespace collision. To avoid writing `std::cout` or `std::cin`, consider `using std::cout` and `using std::cin`. I refactored your code and now it gives correct output:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;

class Graph
{
public:
    static constexpr int MAXN = 100; 

    std::vector <int> adj[MAXN + 1]; //adjacency list
    int visited[Graph::MAXN + 1]; // for 1 based indexing

    Graph(){
        for(int i = 0 ; i <= MAXN ; ++i) adj[i].clear();
        memset(visited, 0, sizeof(visited));
    }

    void addEdge(bool isDirected, int u, int v)
    {
        adj[u].push_back(v);
        if(!isDirected) adj[v].push_back(u);
    }

    void takeInput(bool isDirected, int nodes, int edges){
        for(int i = 0 ; i < edges ; i++){
            int u,v; cin >> u >> v; 
            addEdge(isDirected, u, v);
        }
    }

    void DFS(int source)
    {
        visited[source] = 1;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < adj[source].size() ; ++i){
            int adjNode = adj[source][i];
            if(visited[adjNode] == 0){
                DFS(adjNode);
            } 
        }
    }

    bool isConnected(int source, int destination){
        DFS(source - 1);
        return visited[destination - 1];
    }
};

int main()
{
    int nodes, edges;
    cin >> nodes >> edges;//No. of vertices,number of edges
    Graph g;
    g.takeInput(false, nodes, edges);
    int source, destination;
    cin >> source >> destination; //The vertices to be checked if they are connected
    cout << g.isConnected(source, destination) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```